# turning on the screen from a foreground service

Tags: java, android, screen, android-wake-lock

I trying to launch this camera intent `Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE);` from a foreground service to open the default camera app when the screen is locked but if the screen is off you have to turn on the screen to use the camera app so i was using a wake lock to turn the screen on

`CAM_wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK|PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK| PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), TAG_C);`

but it is deprecated and doesn't work anymore on android 13+ devices.

Is there similar way to turn the screen on from a foreground service?